# I'm having a problem adding a column value

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm having trouble adding value to column 3. Since I already created the 3rd column with text value 'successful'. But I don't know how to select a specific row like from row 46 to 101 in the 3rd column to add another text value. Please help me. My data first has 2 columns and 101 rows

My code:

```
library(tm)
library(e1071)
library(gmodels)
library(pdftools)
library(dplyr)

library(readtext)
data_train_dir <- system.file("/Users/hai/Documents/text_mining_naive_bayes/naive_bayes/all_whitepaper")
Data <- readtext(paste0(data_train_dir, "/Users/hai/Documents/text_mining_naive_bayes/naive_bayes/all_whitepaper/*"),
                       dvsep = "\n")

str(Data)

# add column to dataframe

Data$type <- "successful"
names(Data) <- c('id', 'text', 'type')
Data[1:45,3]
```

Comment: `Data$type[46:101] <- "unsuccessful"`

Comment: Thank you so much. I own you a lot